# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () - couldn't recognize css and js file, they are in same folder(GITHUB PAGES)

Tags: github, github-pages, custom-error-pages

Getting page live on GitHub.

this was when it didn't work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
<script defer src="/script.js"></script>
```

this is now, when it works:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script defer src="script.js"></script>
```

What is the difference? Isn't that the same?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly. the `/` in the `script.js` tells where to find the file. `/` is telling it the "root" of the file system, while `script.js` is telling it relative to this file and "beside" it.

Answer (score 0):

If your html/css/js files are in the same folder, that doesn't mean that `/` is pointing to that folder.

What you can do is find out where it points to and use that in your `link` and `script` tags. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/style.css">
<script defer src="/public/script.js"></script>
```

Passing relative addresses might become problematic in the future. Specially if you use routing in your application.

Comment: "Passing relative addresses might become problematic in the future. Specially if you use routing in your application." Could you explain that in more detail, I'm not shore that I get it. I presume passing relative addresses is what I did, do you think good solution to that would be to get into react when starting with routing, I did that only there so that's my only reference.